# JMeter installation: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, automated-tests

I am trying to install JMeter on a remote VM.

I created VM with debian 8.3 OS and install Java and JMeter but when I'm trying to run JMeter I get the following error:

```
An error occurred: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
```

I tried to set the `DISPLAY` variable also to `:1` and `:0.0`.

I also tried to create a new VM instance with Centos 7.2 OS but I get the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you are fine with headless run, then follow [user guide](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui):

> For non-interactive testing, you may choose to run JMeter without the
>   GUI. To do so, use the following command options:
>
> -n This specifies JMeter is to run in non-gui mode

Otherwise, you can run JMeter in GUI mode using X11 forwarding.